# How does access_process_vm() work in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

AFAIK, the ptrace syscall uses `access_process_vm` to read data from other process. However, different process' address space are isolated, how is that achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes’ address spaces are indeed isolated from each other, but they’re not isolated from the kernel. The kernel always knows the memory layout of all active processes. `access_process_vm` works as follows:

- it [retrieves the memory-management information for the target process](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.9/source/mm/memory.c#L5200) (the kernel already knows about the calling process)
- it [ensures that the pages it wants to read are pinned in memory](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.9/source/mm/gup.c#L1873) (*i.e.* they exist, won’t be freed completely, and are present; this will cause any paged-out pages to be read back in)
- it [maps each remote page in the kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.9/source/include/linux/highmem.h#L16), and copies the requested data in the appropriate direction.

On 64-bit platforms, in the general case (*i.e.* the page isn’t an I/O-remapped page), the mapping in the last step relies on the kernel’s direct physical mapping: the kernel has direct access to all physical memory. On 32-bit platforms with `HIGHMEM`, this might involve creating specific mappings. (The latter is the reason why `kmap`, in the last link above, is defined in `highmem.h` — it’s only needed for `HIGHMEM`.)

Comment: I'm curious that why does `kmap` just rely on direct physical mapping on 64-bit platforms .    When kernel want to access process' memory, I think it still needs to establish a dynamic temporary mapping to that area, which is released after `access_process_vm`

Comment: The kernel can access any page in memory through the direct mapping, it doesn’t need a temporary mapping.

Comment: AFAIK, no matter the mapping is direct or not, the mappings are all recored in kernel's page table to make MMU work. Considering this, for those memory mapped for temporary usage in 64bit platform,  are they firstly recored into page table and freed after calling `access_process_vm` ？

Comment: The direct mapping is set up with permanent entries in the kernel’s page tables, there’s no need to add temporary mappings for anything inside it. That’s the whole point of the direct mapping.

Comment: I see, so it means that kernel create those permanet entries by lazy init, which is invoked when the first time that page is visited?

Comment: No, they are set up permanently during the system boot. See [here for x86](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.9/source/arch/x86/mm/init.c#L508).

Comment: unbelievable, how could such large space mapping be permanently set up? If each page is 4KB, then mapping total 64 TB physical memory will requrie the page table to be size of 16G * each PTE size.

Comment: The kernel uses huge pages ;-).

Comment: [the function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.9/source/arch/x86/mm/init.c#L512) you quote annote that _To access them they are temporarily mapped_ . Why did it say _temporarily_ instead of  _permanently_?

Comment: Good question, I could well be wrong; I’ll check and get back to you!

Comment: looking forward to your reply

Comment: hey bro! is there any proress on this question?

Comment: Yes, from what I can tell all present memory is mapped at least to the PMD level, and much of it ends up with permanent PTEs. I haven’t determined yet whether any PTE created for the physical mapping is ever removed. If you build a kernel with `PTDUMP_DEBUGFS` you can see the page tables yourself ;-).

Comment: interesting! I'm not so familiar with kernel source code. which code snippet can I see that kernel uses huge pages to initailize the mapping?